# Figuring out who is the owner of a Google Spreadsheets form

Tags: security, google-sheets, google-forms

I have noticed that Google spreadsheet form's have URLs in the form of `http://spreadsheets.google.com/viewform?formkey=...`. I don't see anything that relates to the Google account in the URL. There also isn't any information about the Google account that owns the form on the form it self.

This seems like a huge security hole, since anyone can spoof an existing form and pretend to be someone else.

Is there any way to know which Google account is going to get my submitted form data?

Maybe it's embedded on the page somehow? Maybe it can be derived from the URL?

Comment: Google's Picasa does this too, and I'm pretty sure it's intentional. For example, you'd never know the album http://picasaweb.google.com/113310224845895190889 belonged to me, unless I told you. I'm sure Google knows + would reveal the owner under subpoena or similar legal process.

Answer (score 2):

Google Spreadsheet Forms comes under Google Docs.

The form must be shared either with the setting, **Public on the Web** - it will show up in Google Search results or **Anyone who has the link**, anyway you cannot find the e-mail address of the owner of the document. As that would be a great security loop-hole on the side of google, anyone will know what company is doing survey on what and stuff like that.

Also, it may be a Google Apps account too.