# How can I increase the likelihood of having Google Apps Accounts upgraded to Google Accounts?

Tags: google-workspace, google-account

I currently have the standard edition of Google Apps, and I'm eager to have my Google Apps accounts function as Google Accounts. It's my understanding that this is a phased deployment by Google, with people [being contacted via email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2619/how-easy-is-it-to-migrate-all-your-google-account-based-services-to-the-google) when they can upgrade to this service.

I'm wondering if there are any settings I should enable to increase the likelihood for my domain to be upgraded, or if it is purely based on random selection by Google.

Here are some of the settings available in Google Apps:

Now Services and Pre-release Features:

- Automatically add new services when they become available
- Enable pre-release features
- Control Panel: Current version or Next generation.

News, feedback and promotions:

- Receive occasional email notifications about new services or features.
- I am willing to be contacted about this product and my experiences.
- Unsubscribe from all marketing and non-transactional emails.

I have the first three options enabled, but the last three about contacting me disabled. I'm wondering, for those of you that did get upgraded, if you had these last 3 settings enabled or disabled. Or, if you know any other settings that should be enabled/disabled in order to increase my chances of being upgraded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the volunteer sign-up form: https://spreadsheets1.google.com/a/google.com/viewform?hl=en&formkey=dGdfTTA2eGhFT0c0SDVLXzMzMFNwUUE6MA#gid=0

Comment: Since I [can't verify](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6416/figuring-out-who-is-the-owner-of-a-google-spreadsheets-form) that Google indeed owns that form, could you explain how you got the link to that form? I want to make sure I don't get phished.

Comment: Fair enough. You can find it linked from these two locations:http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/05/more-google-applications-coming-for.html and http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/topic.py?topic=28917

Comment: Just an update to @Senseful's concern about Phishing.  Google uses http://spreadsheets.google.com/a/YOURDOMAIN.com to show that YOURDOMAIN is the owner of a form.  In this case, YOURDOMAIN is google.com, as can be seen from the /a/google.com portion of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a blog-post from google explaining how you can sign up:

http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/05/more-google-applications-coming-for.html