# Can I use my Google Apps for domains email address as a Google Profile account?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have an old Gmail account that I only have hanging around for a Google Profile, so I can use things such as Google Reader. Ideally I'd like to use my Gmail a for domains email address for this sort of thing, but it won't accept my email and password on their other apps.

Is there some way I can set this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Create a separate Google Account that happens to use the same email address as your Google Apps account.
2. Upgrade your domain so that your Google Apps account is also a Google Account.

I would not recommend option 1, since then it becomes hard to maintain two separate accounts which look the same. Additionally, it will be much harder to transition to #2 once it is forced on your domain. Within a month or two, the 2nd option will be forced on all domains. I'd recommend [speeding up this process](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6566/how-can-i-increase-the-likelihood-of-having-google-apps-accounts-upgraded-to-goog) if you need it right away.

Note that even with method #2, you cannot use all of Google's services yet. [Here's a list](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182213) of some of the products that you cannot use:

> - Android Developer
> - Buzz
> - Extra Storage
> - Health
> - Powermeter
> - Profiles
> - Web History
> - YouTube

Comment: Google Apps accounts that have been upgraded to full Google Accounts can't have Google Profiles, among other services (like Google Health, YouTube, and others.) That leaves only option #1, but only until all Google Apps accounts are forced to upgrade. So, long term, the answer is no, you can't have a Google Profile with a Google Apps account.

Comment: (I wasn't sure if I should have posted that as an answer, so instead I'm commenting in case you want to edit yours.)